# how to use InStr for fetching the string in this case

Tags: vbscript

I have a file which looks like this:

```
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20140805_152774
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20140925_132714
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20140925_133144
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20140925_133601
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20141104_145839
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20151023_104951
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20151027_072235
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20140825_121209
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20140825_121759
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20140825_123400
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20140827_065126
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20141006_094447
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20141006_110546
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20141008_105947
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20150917_093710
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20151005_190254
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20151205_190255
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20161005_190253
```

I need to read only those lines where the date folder values at the end of the strings in the file are greater than or equal to (date1 = 20140925) or less than and equal to (date2 = 20151005). So my output should look like this:

```
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20140925_132714
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20140925_133144
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20140925_133601
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20141104_145839
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20141006_094447
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20141006_110546
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20141008_105947
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20150917_093710
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20151005_190254
```

I know this could be achieved by `InStr` function but not able to get this together. I tried the below code:

```
Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
    line = inFile.ReadLine
    If (InStr(line, date1) > 0 Or InStr(line, date2) > 0 ) Then writeOutput = True
    If writeOutput Then outFile.WriteLine line
    If InStr(line, date2) > 0 Then Exit Do
Loop
```

This gives me the output like

```
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20140925_132714
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20140925_133144
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20140925_133601
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20141104_145839
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20151023_104951
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20151027_072235
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20140825_121209
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20140825_121759
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20140825_123400
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20140827_065126
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20141006_094447
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20141006_110546
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20141008_105947
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20150917_093710
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20151005_190254
```

The lines below are the unwanted ones and as you can see it is taking the range of dates from end to end, whereas I want it to take folder wise.

```
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20151023_104951
\\srv10219\e\Archive\AllocationListFile\20151027_072235
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20140825_121209
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20140825_121759
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20140825_123400
\\srv10219\e\Archive\Article\20140827_065126
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question adding your attempts matching [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rules.

Comment: @JosefZ - U mean I should edit my que and add the code here which is not working at the moment ?

Comment: Yes, I do mean it exactly.

Comment: @JosefZ - I have edited it and now the post looks like too big. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InStr` is for exact matches. If you want to match a range you need to extract the value from the string and convert it to an integer before doing the comparison, for instance with a regular expression:

```
date1 = 20140925
date2 = 20151005

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\\(\d{8})_\d{6}$"

Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
    line = inFile.ReadLine
    For Each m In re.Execute(line)
      d = CLng(m.Submatches(0))
    Next
    If d >= date1 And d <= date2 Then outFile.WriteLine line
Loop
```

Comment: `Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
 line = inFile.ReadLine
 For Each objFolder In objFSO.GetFolder(line).SubFolders     
  For Each dateval In re.Execute(objFolder)
    dateval1 = CLng(dateval.Submatches(0))
    If (dateval1 >= FromDate And dateval1 <= ToDate)  Then outFile.WriteLine objFolder
  Next
 Next
Loop`

Comment: Thanks ! The whole code which u have given is working fine except the last if statement. My script is not executing this "If d >= date1 And d <= date2 Then outFile.WriteLine line" statement. I have pasted my code as it is above. Sorry couldn't find the formatting while putting a comment.

Comment: I used the Clng function and it is working now . Thanks fo rur help once again !! u r life saver :)